# validation pattern to not to allow a separator at the end of a string

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to Test Driven Developmemt(TDD) and I have been practicing RSpec as my TDD tool. Now, I am trying to validate a pattern in my code. With the current code, all my test passed except the last example in RSPEC test. How can I go about it without breaking other example. Below is what I have done so far.

```
def add(*nums)
  joined_arguments = nums.join(",") 
  list_of_strings = joined_arguments.split(/[, \n]/)
  sum = list_of_strings.inject(0) { |sum, num| sum + num.to_i}
end

RSpec.describe "string calculator" do 
  it "returns zero when an empty string is entered" do 
  expect(add("")).to eq(0) 
  end

  it "returns one when one is entered" do 
  expect(add("1")).to eq(1) 
  end

  it "returns sum of two arguments" do expect(add("1,2")).to 
  eq(3) 
  end

  it "returns sum of two arguments that makes use of split method" do 
  expect(add("1", "1,2")).to eq(4) 
  end

  it "returns sum when split with newlines separators and comma" do 
  expect(add("1,2\n3")).to eq(6) 
  end

  it "returns an error when separator is added to end of an element" do 
  expect(add("1,2,")).to eq("error") 
  end 
end
```

All the examples run except the last example which is more of a validation. How do I go about it without breaking the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
def add(*nums)
  return 'error' if nums.map {|num| num[-1] == ',' }.any?
  joined_arguments = nums.join(",") 
  list_of_strings = joined_arguments.split(/[, \n]/)
  sum = list_of_strings.inject(0) { |sum, num| sum + num.to_i}
end
```

The following line checks if the last character of each of the arguments is `,` and if it is the case it returns true

```
nums.map {|num| num[-1] == ',' }.any?
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You just save me from a sleepless night. The solution worked